# cakephp, link to retrieve status variable

Tags: cakephp

Total n00b in CakePhp

Im trying to link to the view retrieved data from variable $status, defined in the controller, given the simple condition "done" or "pending".

Given the model:

```
<?php
    class Task extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Task';
    var $validate = array(
    'title' => array(
    'rule' => 'notEmpty',
    'message' => 'Title of a task cannot be empty'
    )
    );
}?>
```

The Task Controller:

```
        function index($status=null) {
        if($status == 'done')
        $tasks = $this->Task->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Task.done' => '1')));
        else if($status == 'pending')
        $tasks = $this->Task->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Task.done' => '0')));
        else 
        $tasks = $this->set('Tasks', $this->Task->find('all')); 
        $this->set('tasks', $tasks);
        $this->set('status', $status);
        }
```

And finally The View:

```
<h2>Tasks</h2>

<?php if(empty($Tasks)): ?>         
    There are no tasks in this list
<?php else: ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Created</th>
            <th>Modified</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach ($Tasks as $Task): ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $Task['Task']['title'] ?>
            </td>       
            <td>
                <?php
                if($Task['Task']['done']) echo "Done";
                else echo "Pending";
                ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $Task['Task']['created'] ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $Task['Task']['modified'] ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $this->Html->link('Edit', array('action'=>'edit', $Task['Task']['id'])); ?>
                <?php echo $this->Html->link('Delete', array('action'=>'delete', $Task['Task']['id']), null, 'Are you sure you want to delete this task?'); ?>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php echo $this->Html->link('List Done Tasks', array('action'=>'index','done')); ?><br />
    <?php echo $this->Html->link('List Pending Tasks', array('action'=>'index', 'pending')); ?><br />
```

Clicking the "Done Task" returns an empty list (There are no tasks in this list). Can anyone see what is wrong on the link? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is it supposed to be returning? What is set in the $tasks variable when you set it directly with: `$this->set('tasks', $this->Task->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Task.done' => 1))));` If you dump the contents of the array in $tasks does it give you the correct results?

Comment: Yep. It returns the contents (field: done/pending). Also the query retrieves correct data (5 entries 'done', 4 entries 'pending'). Im just trying to pass to the View the 'done' entries alone (link 1 in the view) and the 'pending' entries (link 2). Like this:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by McWayWeb above to case of the variable is incorrect.

As you are setting lower case vars to use in your view i would make the change there. Change all counts of **Task** in the view to **task**.

I would also consider setting all viewVars at the same time using the below

```
$this->set(compact('tasks','status));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up the casing in the variable name **$Tasks**. In your example you are assigning the array to **$tasks**, but then in your view, your are trying to check a variable names **$Tasks**, which will turn up empty because it has never been properly set.

**Change this line:**

`$this->set('tasks', $tasks);`

**To:**

`$this->set('Tasks', $tasks);`